# HTML - list items on left and right of page, on same lines

Tags: html, css, html-lists, css-float

I am creating a website that is going to be my resume. I have my name centered, I am going to have my contact details below. On the left, I am going to have my address over two lines, and on the right I am going to have my email and phone over two lines. I am using a UL tag for this.

This is my code:

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="fullName">
    <h1 class="title">My Name</h1>
  </div>
  <div>
    <ul style="float:left;">
      <ul>Address Line 1</ul>
      <ul>Address Line 2</ul>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div>
    <ul style="float:right;">
      <ul>T: number here</ul>
      <ul>E: xyz@gmail.com</ul>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

As you can see I have used ul, and I did a quick google and thought using float left and right would work. The right works, but the left doesn't; it is indented from the left of the page, whereas the right is all the way over to the right, here is a screen shot:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2tNt.png)

As you can tell I am a novice and have no background at all in HTML etc.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to achieve the layout you want is to wrap both  elements in a  and apply flexbox to the . You can set the justify-content property to "space-between" to create space between the two  elements. Here's the code:

```
   <div class="container">
        <ul>
            <!-- List 1 content here -->
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <!-- List 2 content here -->
        </ul>
    </div>

     <style>
        .container {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
        }
    </style>
```

Comment: Thank you for this - I am going to look into flexboxes, I am still at the very very early stages of HTML / CSS.

Thanks for taking the time out to contribute an answer!

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use a table:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            My Resume
        </title>
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        </link>
        <style>
            table,td,th{
                    border:0px solid #000
                }
            table{
                width:100%;
                border-collapse:collapse
            }
            td,th{
                width:50%;
                padding-top:0px;
                padding-bottom:0px
            }
            td.center-spanned{
                text-align:center;
            }
            td.right-aligned{
                text-align:right;
                padding-left:0px;
                padding-right:50px
            }
            td.left-aligned{
                text-align:left;
                padding-left:50px;
                padding-right:0px
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th class="center-spanned" colspan="2">
                    <div class="fullName">
                        <h1 class="title">
                            My Name
                        </h1>
                    </div>
                </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="right-aligned">
                    Address Line 1
                </td>
                <td class="left-aligned">
                    T: number here
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="right-aligned">
                    Address Line 2
                </td>
                <td class="left-aligned">
                    E: xyz@gmail.com
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Tables are for tabular data, not layout. That's what CSS is for.

Answer (score 0):

Using `ul`s without `li` tags inside them is really wrong semantically, and is also invalid HTML (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul). You should use a different structure, using `li` tags for the entries inside the outermost `ul`s.

Still, to answer the question: Just reset the default padding for `ul`s by adding `ul { padding: 0; }`

```css
ul {
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="fullName">
    <h1 class="title">My Name</h1>
  </div>
  <div>
    <ul style="float:left;">
      <ul>Address Line 1</ul>
      <ul>Address Line 2</ul>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div>
    <ul style="float:right;">
      <ul>T: number here</ul>
      <ul>E: xyz@gmail.com</ul>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this! :)

I had no idea about default padding. That change, worked beautifully!

Thank you for the feedback about the tags, I will read the link now and implement changes. I want to build good habits now, as I begin my journey with HTML.

Thank you again!